# ID from array NOT in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

It seems that I have to edit my question again - these down votes are getting frustrating...
I have an array of ids and a table to check it with. This is the query I use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE order_id IN (...
```

When this number isn't equal to the number of ids in the array, I need to get those values from the array that I have, that do not exist in the table. Is there a more optimal way to do this than making some temporary table, and selecting from it?

EDIT: For all those suggesting inserting NOT in the first query - I do not need all the rows from my table that do not match the values in the array - I need the values from the ARRAY itself...
 For example, I have an array of three ids - "1","2","3". In the table I have ids "2" and "3". I check the array with my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE order_id IN (1,2,3)
```

I get the number 2 as a result of this query, and that doesn't match the number of ids I have in the array, which is 3. I need a query that will get the missing id from the array I submitted, in this case the id I need is "1"

Comment: It is frustrating how easily people click on the down vote, without reading the whole question...

Comment: Well, SQL isn't really good for arrays. It's good for datasets. That's why your set of values needs to be in the form of a dataset in order for MySQL to be able to get something out of it. It doesn't matter if you store the values into a persistent table or incorporate them into the query in the form of a derived table (`(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3)`) – they must be a *row set* to MySQL so that it can extract and return *rows*.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a clean SQL-only solution, because there's no way to SELECT from an array. However, instead of using a temporary table, you could return all the IDs that *are* found in the table, and do the `NOT` on the PHP side.

So select the result of this into an array, `$existing_orders`:

```
SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE order_id IN (...);
```

Then you have:

```
$all_orders = array(1, 2, 3); // IDs you're looking for
$existing_orders = array(2, 3); // IDs that were found in the table

$not_existing_orders = array_diff($all_orders, $existing_orders);

print_r($not_existing_orders); // Array( [0] => 1 )
```

Comment: Yes, something I started considering myself, more than trying through sql only. Thank you for this, probably will go for it

Answer (score 1):

OK THAT´S clear now:

Then you will have to make something like this:

```
select id from order where id IN ( your list )
```

create a second array with the found values

and then use php array function `array_diff`

Comment: sorry, did not see that Boann wrote the same and more detailed

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from orders where order_id NOT in (...
```

Comment: Either people don't read the questions right, or I didn't make myself clear - I need values from the array I submit, not rows from the table